# Usage of argmax from tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, indexing, convolution, max-pooling

I am trying to use the argmax result of `tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax()` to index another tensor. For simplicity, let's say I am trying to implement the following:

```
output, argmax = tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(input, ksize, strides, padding)
tf.assert_equal(input[argmax],output)
```

Now my question is how do I implement the necessary indexing operation `input[argmax]` to achieve the desired result? I am guessing this involves some usage of `tf.gather_nd()` and related calls, but I cannot figure it out. If necessary, we could assume that input has `[BatchSize, Height, Width, Channel]` dimensions.

Thx for your help!

Mat

Comment: Did you check that input[argmax] itself doesn't work? Tensorflow supports relatively advanced strided slicing (like numpy) so this might just work (though maybe you'll need to apply it to the padded input).

Comment: yes, I checked. That does not work...

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution using `tf.gather_nd`and it works, although it seems not so elegant. I used the function `unravel_argmax`that was posted [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2169%20here).

```
def unravel_argmax(argmax, shape):
    output_list = []
    output_list.append(argmax // (shape[2] * shape[3]))
    output_list.append(argmax % (shape[2] * shape[3]) // shape[3])
    return tf.stack(output_list)

def max_pool(input, ksize, strides,padding):
    output, arg_max = tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(input=input,ksize=ksize,strides=strides,padding=padding)
    shape = input.get_shape()
    arg_max = tf.cast(arg_max,tf.int32)
    unraveld = unravel_argmax(arg_max,shape)
    indices = tf.transpose(unraveld,(1,2,3,4,0))
    channels = shape[-1]
    bs = tf.shape(iv.m)[0]
    t1 = tf.range(channels,dtype=arg_max.dtype)[None, None, None, :, None]
    t2 = tf.tile(t1,multiples=(bs,) + tuple(indices.get_shape()[1:-2]) + (1,1))
    t3 = tf.concat((indices,t2),axis=-1)
    t4 = tf.range(tf.cast(bs, dtype=arg_max.dtype))
    t5 = tf.tile(t4[:,None,None,None,None],(1,) + tuple(indices.get_shape()[1:-2].as_list()) + (channels,1))
    t6 = tf.concat((t5, t3), -1)    
    return tf.gather_nd(input,t6)
```

In case anyone has a more elegant solution, I'd still be curious to know.

Mat

Answer (score 1):

This small snippet works:

```
def get_results(data,other_tensor):
    pooled_data, indices = tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(data,ksize=[1,ksize,ksize,1],strides=[1,stride,stride,1],padding='VALID',include_batch_in_index=True)
    b,w,h,c = other_tensor.get_shape.as_list()
    other_tensor_pooled = tf.gather(tf.reshape(other_tensor,shape= [b*w*h*c,]),indices)
    return other_tensor_pooled
```

The above `indices` can be used to index the tensor. This function actually returns flattened indices and to use it with anything with `batch_size > 1` you need to pass `include_batch_in_index`  as `True` in-order to get proper results. I am assuming here that `othertensor` you has the same batch size as `data.`

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it in this way:

```
def max_pool(input, ksize, strides,padding):
    output, arg_max = tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(input=input,ksize=ksize,strides=strides,padding=padding)
    shape=tf.shape(output)
    output1=tf.reshape(tf.gather(tf.reshape(input,[-1]),arg_max),shape)

    err=tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(output,output1)))
    return output1, err
```

Comment: You must include the parameter `include_batch_in_index=True` for it to work correctly on multiple images